# How did Woody Allen film this dancing scene?

Tags: film-techniques, everyone-says-i-love-you

Since the first day I watched Woody Allen's [Everyone Says I Love You](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everyone_Says_I_Love_You) I couldn't stop wondering: [How on earth was this scene filmed?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUu01nJPoRo&feature=youtu.be&t=1m50s)

The way Goldie Hawn moves is incredibly natural. I literally find it hard to believe that they were using cables to hold her in the air, especially on the parts where she slides back through the floor.

Comment: Any particular reason for changing the title just to mention the director?

Comment: I thought It'd make the question more visible, since there is no "woody-allen" tag and I couldn't create one. We can rollback it to revision 2 if you disagree.

Comment: Well, that's your decision, it doesn't hurt anyone either, I think. In the end I guessed such a reason or something similar. Yet I don't think that this technique is something characteristic for *Woody Allen* (unless convinced of the opposite), so I'm happy you couldn't add the `woody-allen` tag out of nowhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure she's on a wire. Have you tried watching the dvd with directors comments on? I don't know if it exists, but might provide insight.

Comment: I haven't seen any dvd extras about this movie, actually I don't know if there is any... But I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a technique known as **wire work**, often used in martial arts films—see [*Wire fu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_fu).

A wire is attached to a harness under the bodice of her dress is threaded through a pulley on a crane.  Typically a man is on the other end of the line, pulling down to raise her a little, or two men to raise her a lot.  The smooth horizontal movements are made by extending/retracting a telescopic crane, or for limited distances, a stationary crane can be rotated.  You can see some stunt performers training in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlebgX5Uj8g).

In post production, the wire is removed through a technique known as [rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping).